# Understanding domains mentioned in differentiation of nth root

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm came across this theorem in a calculus book:

> Suppose $n$ is an integer, $n \geq 2$ and $f(x) = x^\dfrac{1}{n}$. Then
> $f'(x) = (1/n)x^{\dfrac{1}{n} - 1}$. If $n$ is even then the domain of
> $f'$ is $(0, \infty)$, and if $n$ is odd then it is $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$

I'm having a diffcult time understanding how the domain of $f'$ is satisfied in the above theorem.

Let's take the example of when $n$ is even,

When $n$ is odd, let's consider a case.
When $n=3$, the $f'(x)$ is $\dfrac{1}{3*x^{2/3}} $

Having negative numbers of $x$ will lead to $\sqrt{-1}$ etc. But the domain seems to include negative numbers.

Comment: It should be $f'(x)=\frac{1}{n}x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}$, there seems to be a typo in your book

Comment: @PeterMelech I think that's what I have written in the question too. I guess the `(1/n)` is confusing for the readers.

Comment: Ah, okay. I see what you mean.

Comment: No, the exponent is $\frac{1}{n}-1=\frac{1-n}{n}\neq \frac{1}{n-1}$

Comment: For any real $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ one can show $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ is differentiable with $f'(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$, put $\alpha=\frac{1}{n}$, then the domains have to be chosen in the appropriate way

Comment: @PeterMelech I'm still not able to see how the domain is proper when n is odd. Eg: When $n=3$, the domain seems to be accepts numbers where it will lead to $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: ( I have edited the question to fix the typo and update the question accordingly)

Comment: Why that? $x\mapsto \frac{1}{3}x^{\frac{-2}{3}}$ is well defined within the reals for $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to leave so that I cannot continue this discussion, but I'll be back here

Comment: @PeterMelech Because for negative value of $x$ (Eg: -1), it will become $(-1)^{-2/3}$. I thought that's the same reason why when $n$ is even, the domain for negative numbers is excluded.

Comment: the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^3$ is invertible. $(-1)^{-\frac{2}{3}}=(-1)^{-2}=1$, since $(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}=-1$, more generally the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^n$ is invertible for odd $n$, while $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^n$ isn't invertible for even $n$, in this case you have to consider the restriction $f|_{\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}}:\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^n$.